# Restart setInterval each minute

Tags: javascript, setinterval

To create a ticking movement and not a sliding one of a number on a canvas i want to move the number up in 0,2 secondes and wait 0,8 seconds. The codes works good for a sliding movement but to implement the ticking i get lost.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wetlip/kumy5)

```
var ittt = 0;
var add = null;

function MinuteTimer() {
    add = setInterval(function () {
        totime();
        if (ittt % (40 * 60) == 0) {
            ittt = 0;
        }
    }, 5);
};

function stoptimer() {
    clearInterval(add);
};

function totime() {
    drawcanvasbackground();
    drawnumberscanvas(ittt);
    ittt += 1;
    if (ittt % 40 == 0 && ittt > 0) {
        clearInterval(add);
        setTimeout(MinuteTimer(), 800);
    };
};
```

Comment: `MinuteTimer()` calls the function immediately (whether or not that's actually your issue, I don't know. A http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be nice).

Comment: indeed it runs without "tick". the first time it is called immediately with a buttonclick ,  but why if it is put in  setTimeout(MinuteTimer(), 800); does it being called immediately afterwarts

Comment: Of course, whenever you put `()` after a function reference, the function gets called. `foo(bar())` is evaluated as "call `bar` and then call `foo` with the return value of `bar`". `setTimeout` expects a function reference, just like `setInterval`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wetlip/kumy5/

Comment: you are right , it works without (). thank you . i alway will strugle with the ().